# Exception :weblogic.application.ModuleException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I am trying to upgrade Weblogic 12.1.0 with Weblogic 12.1.1. I have made all the necessary changes in the application. Application was successfully build. But server is not getting started and giving me this exception.

I have checked all the DataSources. They all are working fine.

**EXCEPTION:**

```
<Feb 5, 2018, 2:49:16,498 AM EST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "_appsdir_enterprise-core_jar" due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'com.nextjet.enterprise.affiliate.affiliatemanager.AffiliateManagerHome' didn't find subcontext 'affiliate'. Resolved 'com.nextjet.enterprise'; remaining name 'affiliate/affiliatemanager/AffiliateManagerHome'weblogic.application.ModuleException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'com.nextjet.enterprise.affiliate.affiliatemanager.AffiliateManagerHome' didn't find subcontext 'affiliate'. Resolved 'com.nextjet.enterprise'; remaining name 'affiliate/affiliatemanager/AffiliateManagerHome'
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted denotes a problem looking up a JNDI entry, something which your application references in the description files but was not registered. If you take a look at the JNDI tree on the target you are deploying on with the admin console you should find a com/nextjet/enterprise entry but not the expected com/nextjet/enterprise/affiliate/affiliatemanager/AffiliateManagerHome.

Either an earlier started deployment should have registered some object to this name, or you are missing some configuration item such as a data source. If you still have your 12.1.0 environment running, you could try looking up this entry in the old JNDI tree to figure out what kind of object is at that entry and where in the deployment or bootup process it should have been registered.